# Network fails and won't reinitialize Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, dhcp

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu-Server 14.04 instance.  Nothing is installed yet other than the base system, OpenSSH server, and LAMP server (as selected in the install process).  It is connecting to my network via a wireline Ethernet connection.  It's configured for DHCP by default,

I am trying to restore files to it over the network, via SSH.  (rsync, specifically.)

The connection keeps dropping after an inconsistent amount of time.  (Anywhere from a few minutes to an hour.)  A reboot seems to fix it, but nothing else does.

Running dhclient gives no output, and does not resolve the issue.

Running services networking restart says that there was an error stopping the job, and then couldn't start because it was already running.  It does not resolve the issue.

I tried switching to a static IP and that wouldn't even connect in the first place.

network-manager is not installed.  Trying to install it asks me to install half of Gnome, which makes little sense on a headless server.

Swapping ethernet cables did not help.  Other computers on the same network have rock-solid connections.

My /etc/networking/interfaces file is:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Static configuration of primary network interface
#iface eth0 inet static
#       address 192.168.42.2
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       network 192.168.42.0
#       broadcast 192.168.42.255
#       gateway 192.168.42.1

#dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75
#dns-nameservers 75.75.76.76
```

(The commented out sections at the bottom were my attempt at static configuration.  The dhcp lines are what the installer setup by default.)

Other than rebooting the computer every 30 minutes, any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Can you publish dmesg and /var/log/syslog?